# Get out of full-screen mode?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How do you get out of full-screen mode?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1041/get-out-of-full-screen-mode?/) by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Press F11.

From the [User Guide](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started_gui.html):

```
 View –> Full Screen: Puts the World View into fullscreen (To exit fullscreen mode, press F11 on your keyboard)
```

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on 2013-01-29**:
Thanks!  In future builds, can the hotkeys associated with these functions be listed next to the commands in the Gazebo menus, like they are in the Microsoft Office suite?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-29**:
Issue for this: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/458/list-hotkeys-in-gui